# Does a data source (as in UITableViewDataSource) count as model or controller in MVC paradigm?

Tags: ios, uitableview, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am wondering where an iOS data source (as in `UITableViewDataSource`) fits in the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm: under model or under controller (or where else)?

For instance, the name `UITableViewDataSource` as such would suggest model. But then data sources may be backed by `NSFetchedResultsController`s (as described under ["implementing the Table View Datasource Methods"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW13)) and that name would suggest controller.

Is there a recognized [design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) that provides a rational answer?

Comment: I thought NSFetchedResultsController is a convenient wrapper to transport your data to your view controller ? You don't have to use a NSFetchResults controller, you could very well create a model class called "Book" and then create instances of Book model, store them in an NSArray and feed that to your UITableView.

Comment: I agree with @Zhang you don't have to use NSFetchedResultsController it's an easier way to present your data in a tableView

Comment: @YuviGr Of course ("data sources *may* ...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have by now decided that insofar as a single choice should be taken, data sources are closer to controllers than to models.

The decision is not critical. I use it mainly as a rationale for placing classes that represent data sources in Xcode groups, UML diagrams and the like.